# How to apply Bonferroni correction across multiple regression experiments?

Tags: regression, statistical-significance, multiple-regression, bonferroni

I have 5 variables: A, B, C, and D. A and B are two different scales and are my dependent variables. C (categorical) and D (continuous) are fixed effects. C is also a categorical variable having 3 levels (0,1,2). My goal is to understand if C is a significant predictor when fit against A and B. I analyze this in the following manner:

First, I fit a regression model and assess the p-values of the coefficients of C.

`mod_A = lm(A ~ C + D )`

`mod_B = lm(B ~ C + D )`

The summary of the above two models give me the coefficient of the contrast between 0-1 and 0-2 (when C's base level is set to 0) and its p-value. I change C's base level to 1 and the contrast now being computed are 1-2 and 1-0. Overall I have 3 unique contrast coefficients and their p-values: 0-1, 0-2 and 1-2. I further run another analysis by removing the variable C altogether and comparing it against my full model.

`mod_A_removedC = lm(A ~ D )`

`mod_B_removedC = lm(B ~ D )`

I compare these models to the full models above using the `anova` function (from the car package) to compute the chi-squares statistic and get the p-values.

`anova(mod_A,mod_A_removedC)`

`anova(mod_B,mod_B_removedC)`

Now, how do I adjust these p-value using the bonferroni correction? Should my alpha be 0.05/m, where m = number of unique comparisons in each test(which is 3, since 0-1,0-2 and 1-2) or the over all number of unique hypothesis being tested (across all experiments), which is: 8 (3 (from `mod_A`) + 3 (from `mod_B`) + 1 (from `anova(mod_A,mod_A_removedC)`) + 1(from `anova(mod_B,mod_B_removedC)`))